# Call Picasso from Webview - doesn't work

Tags: android, webview, interface, imageview, picasso

I'm using a JavaScript Interface to load a photo from a URL to a `ImageView` with Picasso:

```
public void DLPhoto(String url) {
    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    Log.e("error", "PICASSO ERROR ----------------");
                }
            })
            .build();
    picasso.load(url).into(dlphotoview);
}


public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{
    private Context context;
    WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context c){
        context = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void makeToast(String url){
        DLPhoto(url);
    }
}
```

The url comes from the JavaScript in the HTML file (that works).
If I start the DLPhoto in my `onCreate` method then it works:

```
DLPhoto("http://... LINK TO THE PHOTO");
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I didnt get any error, also no log Error:
    Log.e("error", "PICASSO ERROR ----------------");

Comment: So then what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesnt load the photo when i call the function DLPhoto() over the "makeToast()". If i call the DLPhoto() when Button is pressed than it works ...

Comment: Ok i found an error in Android Studio, i think it has something todo with it right? 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread .....

I am not allowed to call the picasso.load() over the WebViewJavaScriptInterface

Comment: Perhaps you could set up the class running in the main thread to accept a message for kicking off that function call.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean? How should this look like?